# lattice of von Neumann algebra

Tags: lattice-orders, von-neumann-algebras

Let $L$ be an orthomodular complete lattice of orthogonal projectors  in a complex Hilbert space and $R=L''$ the von Neumann algebra generated by $L$.
Is it true that the lattice of orthogonal projectors in $R$ is $L$ itself?